# Skip first N elements in scala iterable

Tags: scala, sequence

I'd like to know if scala includes a way to skip the first N elements of an iterable, so that for instance

```
(1 to 5).WHATIWANT(3).foreach(println(_))
```

would print only 4 and 5.

I understand there's slice, but if the length of the sequence can't be obtained in advance, like in my case, that's not gonna do.

Ideas?

Comment: You might be interested in this: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Iterable

Answer (score 66, accepted):

```
(1 to 5).drop(3).foreach(println(_))
```

Comment: or just `1 to 5 drop 3 foreach println`