# Reverse list of n elements

Tags: scala

i was given this problem and i thought I had it figured out , but i was told i had it wrong. the question was,. Given a list xs, reverse the first n elements. I guess im not understanding what the question was asking , i thought we take an Int n , and return the first n elements in front of that int n in reverse.

```
def nthRev[T](n: Int,xs: List[T]): List[T] = xs match {
  case List() => List()
  case head :: rest => (head::rest.take(n)).reverse
}
```

so, the output is

```
nthRev(3,List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
```

returns

```
List(4, 3, 2, 1)
```

but apparently its wrong, can anyone explain what the question is asking for?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this pattern? For me, this looks just like a test if the list is empty. Nothing else. For the question itself, I guess the result should be something like `List(4, 3, 2, 1, 5)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I interpret your question "Given a list xs, reverse the first n elements." and the example

```
nthRev(3,List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
```

I would expect it to reverse the first 3 elements, but then leave the rest of the list:

```
List(3, 2, 1, 4, 5)
```

When the question says "first n elements" it is saying to replace "n" with the number given as the first argument in your example "3", to give "first 3 elements". The 3 has nothing to do with the element in the list. Changing your example:

```
nthRev(3,List(10,11,12,13,14)
```

would return

```
List(12,11,10,13,14)
```

Answer (score 3):

I think it means you're supposed to return a new list that has the same elements of the original list, but with the first `n` elements reversed.

```
def nthRev[T](n: Int, xs: List[T]): List[T] =
  xs.splitAt(n) match { case (a, b) => a.reverse ::: b }

nthRev(3, (1 to 5).toList) // List(3, 2, 1, 4, 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go with simple standard API. Have a look at the drop function explained in this post: [Skip first N elements in scala iterable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9514663/skip-first-n-elements-in-scala-iterable)

```
def reverseAtN[a](n: Int, list: List[a]): List[a] =
  List.concat(x.take(n).reverse, x.drop(n))
```